# Zip two file contents having related timestamp column to create a list in python

Tags: python

I have two files containing timestamp column with 1000+ rows. Row in file f1 is related to the row in file f2. I wanted a Python script to do `[f1 nth row,f2 nth row]` for all corresponding rows in the best way possible. Thanks!

```
f1:  
05:43:44  
05:59:32

f2:  
05:43:51  
05:59:39
```

e.g. [05:43:44,05:43:51], [05:59:32,05:59:39] ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
f1_as_list = open(f1).readlines() # get each line as a list element
f2_as_list = open(f2).readlines()
zipped_files = zip(f1_as_list, f2_as_list) # zip the two lists together
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `zip()` function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably the most intuitive approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open("f1.txt") as f1:
  with open("f2.txt") as f2:
    for row1 in f1:
      for row2 in f2:
        print("%s %s" % (row1.strip(), row2.strip()))
```

Some might prefer a list comprehension, but non-pythonistas may not consider it intuitive.

```
with open("f1.txt") as f1:
  with open("f2.txt") as f2:
    print("\n".join([
      "%s %s" % (row1.strip(), row2.strip())
      for row1 in f1
      for row2 in f2
    ]))
```